# The code below shows the extracting data from graph db using node js. the data is extracting fine but when I use filter (where) it gives empty result

Tags: node.js, gremlin, graph-databases, gqlquery

```
    g.v()
  .has('label','Event')
  .not(has('active',false)).as('Event').order().by('createdTimestamp', decr)
  .project('label','event', 'user')
  .by(constant('Livestream'))
  .by(
    __.select('Event')
    .project('id', 'label', 'name', 'cover', 'description', 'allowComments', 'active', 'hashtags', 'partitionValue', 'userId', 'createdTimestamp', 'createdDate')
  .by('id').by('label').by('name').by('cover').by('description').by('allowComments')
  .by(
    coalesce(
      values('active'),
      constant(true)
    )
  )
  .by('hashtags')
  .by('partitionValue').by('userId').by('createdTimestamp').by('createdDate')
  )
  .by(
    __.in('USERcreatedEVENT')
    .project('id', 'privacy', 'label', 'email', 'username', 'name',  'displayPic')
    .by('id').by('privacy').by('label').by('email').by('username').by('name').by('displayPic')
  )
.where(select('privacy').is(eq('PUBLIC')))
```

This is the code from where I need data by filtering on the basis of user privacy. I am doing in this way but it is not working can you help me in this regard. The code below shows the extracting data from graph db using node js. the data is extracting fine but when I use filter (where) it gives empty result. If you still need some information do ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it right, then you are trying to filter the results where `privacy` property of the `in` vertex is equal to `public`.

I can tell you why this query is returning empty results. Because the `privacy` label is not set and when you write `select('privacy')`, there is no such label and hence equality comparison with non existing label filters out everything.

you can try :

```
g.V().
  has('label', 'Event').
  not(has('active', false)).as('Event').
  order().by('createdTimestamp', decr).
  project('label', 'event', 'user').
    by(constant('Livestream')).
    by(
      select('Event').
      project( 'id', 'label', 'name', 'cover', 'description', 'allowComments',
        'active', 'hashtags', 'partitionValue', 'userId', 'createdTimestamp',
        'createdDate').
        by('id').  by('label').  by('name').  by('cover').  by('description').
        by('allowComments').  by(coalesce(values('active'), constant(true))).
        by('hashtags').  by('partitionValue').  by('userId').  by('createdTimestamp').
        by('createdDate')).
    by(
      in('USERcreatedEVENT').
      project( 'id', 'privacy', 'label', 'email', 'username', 'name', 'displayPic').
        by('id').  by('privacy').  by('label').  by('email').  by('username').
        by('name').  by('displayPic')).
  where(select('Event').in('USERcreatedEVENT').has('privacy', 'PUBLIC'))
```